# Xamarin Android App will not deserialize Size and Point when Linking is None

Tags: android, xml, serialization, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an android app where I save the report layout in XML format.  Each field has a System.Drawing.Size Size and a System.Drawing.Point Location.

The XML for a Point is

```
<Location>
    <X>32</X>
    <Y>40</Y>
</Location>
```

The XML for a Size is

```
<Size>
    <Width>600</Width>
    <Height>56</Height>
</Size>
```

The object contains properties for the same as

```
    private Size _Size = new Size(50, 20);
    public Size Size
    {
        get
        {
            return _Size;
        }
        set
        {
            bool DoEvent = true;
            if (value.Height == _Size.Height && value.Width == _Size.Width)
                DoEvent = false;
            _Size = value;
            if (DoEvent)
                OnPropertyChanged("Size");
        }
    }
```

and

```
    private System.Drawing.Point _Location;
    public System.Drawing.Point Location
    {
        get
        {
            return _Location;
        }
        set
        {
            _Location = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Location");
        }
    }
```

I create the Serialzer as follows

```
    public static void NewSerializer()
    {
        Type[] extraTypes = new Type[7];
        extraTypes[0] = typeof(MPSReportPage);
        extraTypes[1] = typeof(MPSReportField);
        extraTypes[2] = typeof(MPSTextField);
        extraTypes[3] = typeof(MPSImageField);
        extraTypes[4] = typeof(Margins);
        extraTypes[5] = typeof(Size);
        extraTypes[6] = typeof(System.Drawing.Point);

        try
        {
            ReportSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MPSReportDocument), extraTypes);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        //ReportSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MPSReportDocument));
    }
```

The Point and Size were not there as extraTypes originally but I added them to try to resolve the issue.

This all deserializes fine if I set Linking to None.  If I set Linking to SDK Only, both field types deserialize to 0, 0.  All other field types deserialize fine.  Thanks in advance for any help with this.

https://github.com/JimWilcox3/XMLSerializerTest

Is a link to a Visual Studio solution that shows the problem.

Comment: What is the exception when you deserialize? (Assuming a missing class/property?)

Comment: The X and Y of Location are 0 and the Width and Height of Size are 0.  I don't think there is anything missing since it works in Linking = None and Doesn't work in Linking = Sdk Assemblies Only.  I am going to add a link to a git repo of a solution that indicates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been sent to Microsoft and they are working on it.  After looking through my code, though, I realized that I never pass a Size or Point to any native functions.  I just use the Width/Height or X/Y to figure out where to draw the object.  So what I did was just create my own Point and Size objects as so:

```
[Serializable]
public class Point
{
    public Point()
    {
    }

    public Point(int X, int Y)
    {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
    }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Size
{
    public Size()
    {
    }

    public Size(int Width, int Height)
    {
        this.Width = Width;
        this.Height = Height;
    }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

And then in my deserializer, I made the extra types as:

```
public static void NewSerializer()
{
    Type[] extraTypes = new Type[7];
    extraTypes[0] = typeof(MPSReportPage);
    extraTypes[1] = typeof(MPSReportField);
    extraTypes[2] = typeof(MPSTextField);
    extraTypes[3] = typeof(MPSImageField);
    extraTypes[4] = typeof(Margins);
    extraTypes[5] = typeof(Size);
    extraTypes[6] = typeof(Point);

    try
    {
        ReportSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MPSReportDocument), extraTypes);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }

    //ReportSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MPSReportDocument));
}
```

I had to fully qualify them when I used them elsewhere in the app, but it was a small price to pay for a 20-30 MB smaller app size.

Answer (score 1):

In your `.csproj`, add the **`Mono.Android`** assembly to the **`AndroidLinkSkip`** within a `PropertyGroup` property for your `Release` configuration (or `Debug` if desired).

```
<AndroidLinkSkip>Mono.Android</AndroidLinkSkip>
```

Or add it via the IDE:

[image]

You would need to review the `Sweep` step of the `monolinker` to determine the exact element(s) that are being stripped to create a xml descriptor file that only prevents those needed types from being removed, but disabling linking on the entire `Mono.Android` assembly will definitely work and allow your XML deserialization to function properly.

Comment: Ignoring Mono.Android works, but I think that Mono.Android IS the SDK Assembly.  When I ignore it, the app goes from 9 MB to 36 MB.  So how can I review the sweep step of the linking process?  I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @JimWilcox `Mono.Android` is just one of the SDK assemblies, `SDKOnly` Android linking includes "framework". I have my own custom linker step that I use during release preparations to create custom descriptor files, you can review the `monolinker` code @ https://github.com/mono/linker

Comment: Can you add this step in Visual Studio?  This is a bit above my level of expertise, but I'm game to try with proper instructions.

Comment: @JimWilcox It actually alters one of the internal `.targets` steps to include the custom step "plugin" into the linker, then it produces a remove/keep sweep report. I've never gotten around to publishing the code or the altered target... to be honest I assumed Xamarin would have done it by now. I should do a PR for it into Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android and the linker itself since the .Net Core group has now adopted the linker as a part of their official build process... :-) just need to find the time.

Comment: Would you be willing to run my test through your special linker and let me know the Assembly full name and Type full names for the Size and Point that are getting removed from the serialization?  We kind of know it's Mono.Android, but I think there are sub assemblies within that.  I fixed another serialization problem with a linked exclude for System.Runtime.Serialization.